# How to prevent clicking on GestureDetector child Flutter

Tags: flutter, gesturedetector, iconbutton

I'm having a button inside a `GestureDetector`. Both the `GestureDetector` and the `IconButton` have their own function. However, I just want to execute the function of `GestureDetector` instead of ```IconButton`` when tapping on the icon. I know some solutions for this proble, but I still wonder in the case above, is there any solution that prevent flutter from executing the IconButton's function?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add your code snippet that you are trying to solve? Because while`GestureDetector` having single child `IconButton`, only icon button will be tappable here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tap priority child> GesuterDetector. If you have a single child as `IconButton` on `GestureDetector` only `IconButton` will work.

Let's say you have a column instead.

- you can pass null on `onPressed` of `IconButton` based on condition.
- using `AbsorbPointer` will prevent tap event of its child, and `GestureDetector` tap event will work in this case.
- `IgnorePointer` will totally ignore any tap event in its area.

**Demo Widget**

```dart
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget();
  // final String title;

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  bool _disableIconButton = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                print("GestureDetector Tapped");
              },
              child: IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  print(" only Icon will be working here");
                },
                icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 100,
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                print("GestureDetector Tapped");
              },
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Text("Inside Column"),
                  Switch(
                    value: _disableIconButton,
                    onChanged: (v) {
                      setState(() {
                        _disableIconButton = v;
                      });
                    },
                  ),

                  ///* Colors will faded on
                  IconButton(
                    onPressed: _disableIconButton
                        ? null
                        : () {
                            print("Icon null checker tapped");
                          },
                    icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                  ),

                  ///* Colors will faded on like disable and will work on GuesterTap
                  AbsorbPointer(
                    absorbing: _disableIconButton,
                    child: IconButton(
                      onPressed: _disableIconButton
                          ? null
                          : () {
                              print("Icon AbsorbPointer tapped");
                            },
                      icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                    ),
                  ),

                  ///* it will ignore tap event
                  IgnorePointer(
                    ignoring: _disableIconButton,
                    child: IconButton(
                      onPressed: _disableIconButton
                          ? null
                          : () {
                              print("Icon IgnorePointer tapped");
                            },
                      icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Solution 2: Write a separate function and pass a parameter to trigger that function based on your requirement.`

About this. I think he meant that you have 2 functions now that you call if user tap the icon/button:

```
tapIcon() {//do this and that}

tapButton() {//do this and that}
```

Then you create a 3rd function that has an argument on which you decide which function should be called:

```
callFunc(bool iconTap) {
   iconTap ? tapIcon() : tapButton();
}
```

And you use this on the onTap/onPressed: `() {callFunc(true/false);}`

Or you can use enum if you are planning to have more functions:

```
enum FunctionsEnum { BUTTON, ICON }
```

```
callFunc(FunctionsEnum functionsEnum) {
   if (functionsEnum == FunctionsEnum.BUTTON) tapButton();
   if (functionsEnum == FunctionsEnum.ICON) tapIcon();
}
```

Then pass an enum: `onTap: () {callFunc(FunctionsEnum.BUTTON);}`

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**: You can just provide an empty function to `IconButton onPressed method`.

**Solution 2**: Write a separate function and pass a parameter to trigger that function based on your requirement.

Comment: Can you explain more about the soluion 2?